# How to set MKMapView maptype without using attribute?

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

Currently learning iOS development. I need to set my instance of `MKMapView` to display with satellite view. I know I can do this through the attribute settings, but I wish to do it through code using `[myMapView setMapType:MKMapTypeSatellite]`, but my question is, where do I put this so that as soon as the mapView loads on the screen, it is already in satellite mode. My instinct is to send this message once my instance of mapview is instantiated, but where does this occur?

Comment: try putting it in viewDidLoad?

Answer (score 1):

Typically this type of code is put into the view controller's `viewDidLoad` method, which is called once for each instance of a controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    myMapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,200)];
    myMapView.mapType = MKMapTypeSatellite;
    [self.view addSubview:myMapView];
}
```